# writing an object to a file in cpp

Tags: c++, oop, file

I am trying to write the contents of an object into a file. This is my code

```
void Write_data_intoFile(Customer c1)
{
ofstream fout("cust_details.txt", ios::out | ios::app); 
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&c1),sizeof c1);
fout.close();
}
```

This is how i call the function

```
c[ Customer_count ].Write_data_intoFile(c[ Customer_count ]);
```

The program works fine, but the contents are not written in the file. It shows a red colour mark saying it cannot open the file. How to solve this

```
class Customer
{
char name[25];
int id;
}
```

I created the objects, globally, by

```
Customer c[20];
```

I am trying to write it in a text format

Comment: Instead of passing c1, you can use `this` to get a pointer to the object who's member function is being invoked. So instead of `fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&c1),sizeof c1);`, use `fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (this),sizeof *this);
`

Comment: first of all, you can make that function either static or remove the Customer argument. So you call it like either Customer::Write_data_intoFile(c1) or c1.Write_data_intoFile(); also, it seems like you out of range as Custome_count probably holds the size of the container.

Comment: If `Customer` contains any pointer or reference members (directly or indirectly), simply writing out the object as a binary blob will not work. The resulting file will also not be portable to other architectures.

Comment: Are you trying to write as text or binary? If you are trying to write as text then the code above will not work. If you are trying to write as binary then it *may* not work and it could be improved. You need to explain more precisely what you are trying to do, what the problem actually is ('it shows a red colour mark' means nothing to me) and finally you need to post the definition of your Customer class. Without these details it's hard to help.

Comment: @Viktor Sehr Why it has to be static if it's not a member function?

Comment: @Kim: Viktor is wrong (in my opinion), now why not supply the information that people need to actually help you.

Comment: @ john. I am trying to write it as text.. Red colour mark, i meant, when opening it in ubuntu.. it displays `gedit has not been able to detect the character coding.
Please check that you are not trying to open a binary file.
Select a character coding from the menu and try again.` I ll add the class definition in my edit, now

Comment: @Kim, OK well the method you have picked is for binary I/O, so it isn't going to work for text. If you want text you should do something else. Without seeing the definition of Customer I can't say what that should be. So edit your question to include the definiton of Customer, and to say that you want text output.

Comment: @john. Can u tell me what function to use, if i shud write in text?

Comment: @john, i have made the needful edits

Comment: Do you really have just `class { char name[25]; int id; }`? That would make name and id private, with no way of accessing them.

Comment: the function is a member function.. i set the values to the objects through a constructor

Comment: @Viktor: Well I thought your answer wasn't relevant to his actual problem. Making the function a member or a static member is a style issue and would have contributed nothing to CHID actually getting his code to work.

Comment: @CHID: What? It is a member function. I think your code must have more issues that I realised. The way you have written it, it shouldn't be a member function. If it is a member function then Viktor is right (apologies Viktor).

Comment: @CHID, Viktor: I've gone back over the post. Viktor is right, I am right. You method of doing I/O was completely wrong, and something like what I suggested is better. But Viktor correctly identified that you have serious problems with your code which you also need to fix.

Comment: @john: thank you, and btw thats I posted it as a comment, and not as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, first you need to write a function for text I/O of Customer. Traditionally that function is called operator<<. So you need something like this

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Customer& c)
{
  return out << c.name << ' ' << c.id << '\n';
}
```

Maybe (it's hard to be sure) you need to declare this function as a friend of your Customer class, if you get errors about access or private then you probably need to add this line

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Customer& c);
```

inside your Customer class.

Then you need to call this function from inside your other function, like this

```
void Write_data_intoFile(Customer c1)
{
  ofstream fout("cust_details.txt", ios::out | ios::app); 
  fout << c1;
  fout.close();
}
```

Then you really need to read a good book on C++, it's hard to get this stuff right otherwise. Any problems post again.

Comment: and, yes i do know about friend concepts :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reinventing the wheel in a potentially dangerous way [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) can solve this for you, hiding the dirty details.