# Read word by word from file in cpp

Tags: c++, file

I tried to read word by word from a file and store it in corresponding array in cpp. I am facing problems in executing it. Can you guys help me find the problem. This is my code

```
void Read_file()
{
  int i=1;

  ifstream in_file("cust_details1.txt"); 
  if(in_file.is_open())
  {
    cout<<"List of all bills:\n"<<endl;
    while(in_file){
      cout<<"here";
      in_file >> ac_no[i];
      in_file >> ac_name[i];
      in_file >> ac_amount[i];
      in_file >> ac_emi[i];
      in_file >> ac_sanc[i];
      cout<<"Accout no = "<<ac_no[i]<<" Name = "<<ac_name[i]<<" Amount = "<<ac_amount[i]<<" Emi = "<<ac_emi[i]<<" Sanction = "<<ac_sanc[i] <<endl;
      i++;
      cout<<"----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    }
    in_file.close();
    tot=i;
  }
  cout<<"Exiting"<<endl;
}
```

This code executes well for the first time of the loop. i.e first set of records is being stored in the array. When the loop goes for second time, it runs into a seg fault. the `here` is not being printed for second time. All declarations are made correctly.

```
Declarations:
string ac_name[30];
int ac_no[30];
string ac_sanc[2];  // it will hold only y or n
float ac_emi[30];
int ac_amount[30];
```

Comment: Where is ac_no, ac_name etc. being initialized and what is it being initialized to?

Comment: is that condition check operational? I wasn't aware `ifstream`s zeroed themselves when they reached EOF...? (might be better/clearer to use `while(in_file.good())`)

Comment: sorry guyz, prob got solved. It was a silly mistake as pointed out by `Anteru`

Comment: 1. Arrays in C++ start with 0, not with 1, so your `int i=1;` is dubious. 2. Show the declarations, don't proclaim them correct. Better yet, construct a standalone compilable runnable example that demonstrates the problem, and post it in its entirety. It should not be too hard, just add `main()` and `ac_*` declarations and `#include`s to your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your  `while` loop should look like this:

```
while(in_file >> ac_no[i] &&
      in_file >> ac_name[i] &&
      in_file >> ac_amount[i] &&
      in_file >> ac_emi[i] &&
      in_file >> ac_sanc[i])

    cout<<"Accout no = "<<ac_no[i]<<" Name = "<<ac_name[i]<<" Amount = "<<ac_amount[i]<<" Emi = "<<ac_emi[i]<<" Sanction = "<<ac_sanc[i]<<endl;
    i++;
}
```

Such loop ensures that if there is any error in file, it will stop reading.

By the way, the size of each array should be large enough to hold all values in the file. You've declared each array of size `30` except `string ac_sanc[2]`. Why the size of `ac_sanc` is only `2`? You know what it means? It means `ac_sanc[i]` would invoke *undefined behavior* for `i >=2`. Your program might (and most likely will) crash. Also, if it can be only `y` or `n`, then why don't you declare it as `char` array?

Since you're using C++, I would suggest you to define a struct and use `std::vector` as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Account
{
    std::string ac_name;
    int         ac_no;
    char        ac_sanc;
    float       ac_emi;
    int         ac_amount;
};

std::vector<Account> accounts;
Account ac;

while(in_file >> ac.ac_no &&
      in_file >> ac.ac_name &&
      in_file >> ac.ac_amount &&
      in_file >> ac.ac_emi &&
      in_file >> ac.ac_sanc)

     accounts.push_back(ac);
     //...
     //you may use 'ac' to print each values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're writing into the second element in the first loop (`ac_no[1]`, instead of `ac_no[0]`.) If your array is of size 2, then this might explain why it crashes.

If you can't control the input, you shoud use `std::vector` and `push_back` or at least check if `i < arraySize` to catch mistakes like this.

Comment: a.k.a. all CHID's array indicies are off by one, yea?

Comment: @CHID: Why would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.

```
while(in_file)
```

will not fail when you reach the end or have an error, instead prefer:

```
while(in_file.good())
```

Next:

```
string ac_sanc[2];  // it will hold oly y or n
```

This should probably be:

```
char ac_sanc[30];
```

However, as [suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132727/writing-an-object-to-a-file-in-cpp/7132749#7132749), you should probably read up on serialisation techniques. What is going to happen when your "cust_details1.txt" has **thirty** (you're only using indexes from 1, where arrays are zero-based) entries?

And please, please learn to indent your code!